# Find string in csv and add to each line

Tags: php, mysql, bash, csv, unix

I have a csv file I fetch from an API and want to load into a MySQL table, I am unsure what to search for to deal with the unusual nature of the file.

CSV looks something like:

```
meta data
Class 1
1,2,3
5,9,7
Class 2
2,5,4
6,5,4
Class 3
8,4,3
7,8,8
```

I would like the output to be something I can load more easily:

```
Class 1,1,2,3
Class 1,5,9,7
Class 2,2,5,4
Class 2,6,5,4
Class 3,8,4,3
Class 3,7,8,8
```

I'm used to API's returning json's and looping through it in PHP to load the data. This API only has a csv option - the classes always come through in the same order, so i'm thinking maybe a do until loop to append the first value and just repeating it after it runs into the next line which contains 'Class' then rinse and repeat. Not sure if there is an easier way to go about it.

Comment: I think what you are thinking is the only way to make the data into required/appropriate format. You've to a write script which will convert the original data into required format.

Comment: The source data is in a groupbreak format and you want to transform it into a csv format. Read line by line. If you find "Class ..", remember it but don't write to output yet. Next line(s): as long as numberlist is found, concat "Class " variable and numberline to a new string and write it to output. If you encounter a new "Class .." rince and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

With sed :

```
$ sed '/^Class/{h;d};/^Class/!{G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/g}' file.csv
Class 1,1,2,3
Class 1,5,9,7
Class 2,2,5,4
Class 2,6,5,4
Class 3,8,4,3
Class 3,7,8,8
```

Use the `-i` option to edit the file *in place*:

```
sed -i '/^Class/{h;d};/^Class/!{G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/g}' file.csv
```